# C# WFA - How to make a string list sort in the same positions as a sorted integer list

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a high score system for a quiz game I have made. I have got all the scores and their names to read in, sort the scores and put them in rich text boxes (one for scores, one for their names). After I used `.Sort()` on the integer list (scores), the scores were in the correct order but the names (string list) no longer matched up with the scores.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class frmhighScore : Form
{
    public frmhighScore()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Name = "High Score";
    }
    string[] contains;
    string[] scorenames;
    List<int> scores = new List<int>(){ };
    List<string> names = new List<string>(){ };

    private void highScore_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scores.Clear();
        names.Clear();

        scorenames = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "scorenames.txt");


        foreach (string line in scorenames)
        {
            gameClass.scorenames.Add(line);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < gameClass.scorenames.Count(); x++)
        {
            contains = gameClass.scorenames[x].Split(':');
            names.Add(contains[0]);
            scores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(contains[1]));
        }         

        scores.Sort();
        scores.Reverse();

        for (int a = 0; a < scores.Count; a++)
        {

        }

        for (int y = 0; y < names.Count(); y++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += names[y];
            richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
        for (int z = 0; z < scores.Count(); z++)
        {
            richTextBox2.Text += scores[z];
            richTextBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

**gameClass.scorenames** is a string list in my class which is used to read in the details from the text file. All ofther variables are local.

**richTextBox1** is for the names and **richTextBox2** is for the scores

Here is a screenshot of what the form currently looks like:

[Current high score form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEWhN.png)

And here is the text file that I am reading in from **(scorenames.txt)**:

```
r:6
bob:10
```

So as you can see, the names are not matched up with the sorted scores

**So my final question is,** how would I make it so that the names **(bob / r)** match up with their scores **r is 4, bob is 10**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to re model your display entity to bundle both Name and Score together. You might need to change your code somewhat similar to below snippet (I haven't taken care of new line format though)

```
 public class DisplayCard
    {
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

List<DisplayCard> ScoreCard = new List<DisplayCard>();

for (int x = 0; x < gameClass.scorenames.Count(); x++)
            {
                contains = gameClass.scorenames[x].Split(':');
                var name = contains[0];
                var score = Convert.ToInt32(contains[1]);
                ScoreCard.Add(new DisplayCard { Name = name, Score = score });
            }

var sortedCard = ScoreCard.OrderBy(o => o.Score).ToList();

foreach (var card in sortedCard)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += card.Name;
            richTextBox2.Text += card.Score;
            /* take care of new line logic*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might create objects for each player which includes their score. Then use LINQ to sort them by the score, which will then retain the association with their name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

Comment: How would I go about adding each user from the text file to a new object?

Comment: Read the file one line at a time, split the string on ":" into an array.
Then create a new object with the name and score properties from this.
You should parse the score to an integer, easier to work with.